# Fetch Own Feed From Facebook API

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I know this question has been asked a lot, but with the latest changes to Facebook I'm having a hard time figuring out how to accomplish this task.  Many tutorials and answers are no longer relevant due to these changes.

What I want to do is fetch my own personal Facebook feed posts (my posts) and display them on a "News" section on my website.  I want to use the Graph API as the [Facebook Page social plugins](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/) have strange width restrictions that do not work for me.

To access my OWN posts on my OWN feed to place on my OWN website, I seem to be having a hard time getting a working access token.  Do I need to do a "Facebook Login" for permission handling?

I've created a Facebook Developer account, created an App and seem to be successfully fetching a token with the following code:

```
let myToken = ''

fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=${id}&client_secret=${secret}&grant_type=client_credentials`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(token => (myToken = token.access_token))
  .catch(e => console.log(e))
```

When I go to use that token:

```
fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/me/feed?limit=10&fields=id%2Cfull_picture%2Ccreated_time%2Cfrom%7Bid%2Cname%2Cpicture%7D%2Cmessage%2Clink%2Ctype%2Cshares%2Cobject_id%2Cstory&access_token=${myToken}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(e => console.log(e))
```

I'm getting an error:  **An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.**

I don't want any user interaction (commenting, "likes", etc), all I simply want is to read the message and load an image if one is present.  I'll refer the visitor to a 
"View On Facebook" link for the interaction.

Using the Graph API Explorer Tool, I am able to successfully get data but I need to choose "Get User Access Token" and select a bunch of permissions.

I can take the token from Graph API Explorer and get my desired code working but it only lasts 1 hour (short lived) to 2 months (long lived). And would rather not continually update a hard-coded token into my page.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I don't want any user interaction" - it would be really weird (and highly dangerous) if you could just get an access token without user interaction.

Comment: @luschn I should clarify - by "user interaction" I mean I don't want the ability to "like" or leave a comment.  I simply just want a list of posts to appear with a link back to the Facebook post so visitors could like/comment there.

Comment: @Justin. Were you able to figure this out? I'm trying to do the exact same thing.

Comment: @C_blunt, Adding the Facebook feed to my clients website was a "would be cool if it was easy to implement, but not a necessity" feature.  In the end, we decided that the hassle of manually updating the token every 60 days didn't justify the use of the API.  We've instead built a custom news section on their website with a simple CMS.  Understandably, Facebook is tightly controlling their API right now.  Hopefully things will be a little more relaxed in the future and I'll revisit this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using the correct Access Token for this request.

You should be using the *User Token* instead of the *App Token* (the one with the | in between) for this request.

I tried your code with my own tokens and when using the *User Token* it gives me back a data object (in my case empty).

When using the *App Token*, the Graph API responds with the *"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."* message, same as you are getting.

Read more about the Access Tokens on this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out I was using the wrong token.  So, my best approach is to use the Graph API Explorer to generate a long lived user token with the necessary permissions and update the code in my app every 60 days (before it expires)?  Is there any difference if its a business facebook page?

Comment: i thought that this would be about a user profile, not a page? those are two different things. anyway, for a user profile, the only way is to use a long living user token and to refresh it every 2 months - there is no way to automate this.

Comment: @Justin Yes, I'm afraid you will need to update the User Token every 60 days. Don't know of there is any difference between a user profile or a business page.